# For a large number of layers of curly braces, how do I have VSCode render multiple collapse indicators?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For a couple of layers of curly braces "{}", when I move mouse to the line number, there are multiple down arrows that indicate the code block can be collapsed.

[image]

For a large number of layers of curly braces "{}", when I move mouse to the line number, there is only one arrow that indicates the code block can be collapsed

[image]

How do I have VSCode render multiple collapse indicators?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can read about [folding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding) in Visual Studio Code.
As you can it provides syntax aware folding for language as `Markdown, HTML, CSS, LESS, SCSS, and JSON.`

I recommend you try change the setting for your language as indentation as mentioned in the document.
Below example HTML.

```
  "[html]": {
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
  },
```